# WPF thickness keyframe not working

Tags: wpf, vb.net, .net-4.0

I used to animate my border with a from to animation but now I wanted to add a thicknesskeyframe to make it look better. I'm using .net 4.0 and vb.

```
        Dim t As New ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames()
        t.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
        Dim instance As ThicknessKeyFrame
        instance.Value = New Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0)
        instance.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.0)
        t.KeyFrames.Add(instance)
        Dim instance2 As ThicknessKeyFrame
        instance2.Value = New Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1)
        instance2.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)
        t.KeyFrames.Add(instance)
```

I can't instantiate the thickness keyframe I think it's an interface but I don't know how to use it in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fistly, you need to instantiate your instances

```
Dim instance As New DiscreteThicknessKeyFrame()
```

the bottom line is incorrect:

```
t.KeyFrames.Add(instance)
```

it should be

```
t.KeyFrames.Add(instance2)
```

Comment: sorry, was a typo - try my solution again